# How to filter case-insensitive in csvloop

Tags: macros, csv, csvsimple

I have a command like this:

```
\newcommand{\contactdetails}[1]{%
    \csvloop{%
        file={authors.csv},%
        filter equal={#1}{\name},%
        command=\printcontact,%
        head=true,%
        head to column names=true%
    }%
}%
```

it filters authors.csv for and entry with the same name as the first argument and then calls \printcontact.

This works fine, but only when the casing is exactly the same. For example, "John McDonald" wouldn't match "John Mcdonald". Is there a way to make the filter case-insensitive?

I tried

```
\newcommand{\contactdetails}[1]{%
    \csvloop{%
        file={authors.csv},%
        filter equal={\uppercase{#1}}{\uppercase{\name}},%
        command=\printcontact,%
        head=true,%
        head to column names=true%
    }%
}%
```

but that still filters case-sensitive.

Why doesn't this work and what should I do to make `csvloop` filter case-insensitive?

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{authors.csv}
name,phone,mail
John McDonald,123-456-789,a@b.cc
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand{\printcontact}[1]{%
\name: \phone
}%
\newcommand{\contactdetails}[1]{%
    \csvloop{%
        file={authors.csv},%
        filter equal={#1}{\name},%
        command=\printcontact,%
        head=true,%
        head to column names=true%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
\contactdetails{John McDonald} % Works
\contactdetails{John Mcdonald} % Doesn't work :(
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: To compare the result of macros, you could try `filter strcmp =` (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by extending a bit the `l3` version of `csvsimple`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
name,phone,mail
John McDonald,123-456-789,a@b.cc
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \ifcsvstrcmpfoldcase { m m }
  {
    \str_compare:eNeTF {\str_foldcase:e { #1 }} = {\str_foldcase:e { #2 }}
  }
\keys_define:nn { csvsim }
  {
    filter~strcmp~foldcase .meta:n = { filter~test = \ifcsvstrcmpfoldcase #1 },
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\printcontact}[1]{%
  \name: \phone
}

\newcommand{\contactdetails}[1]{%
  \csvloop{
    file=\jobname.csv,
    filter strcmp foldcase={#1}{\name},
    command=\printcontact,
    head=true,
    head to column names=true
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\contactdetails{John McDonald}

\contactdetails{John Mcdonald}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to extend the available keys, you can fold case in the arguments:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
name,phone,mail
John McDonald,123-456-789,a@b.cc
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }
\cs_new_eq:NN \foldcase \str_foldcase:e
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\printcontact}[1]{%
  \name: \phone
}

\newcommand{\contactdetails}[1]{%
  \csvloop{
    file=\jobname.csv,
    filter strcmp={\foldcase{#1}}{\foldcase{\name}},
    command=\printcontact,
    head=true,
    head to column names=true
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\contactdetails{John McDonald}

\contactdetails{John Mcdonald}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why my naive approach with \uppercase didn't work?

Comment: @akichii `\uppercase` is not expandable.